# scrollView in Swift provides error in content size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

In my storyboard I ctrl-dragged a `UIScrollView` in my VC and connected it with a property in my code.

Now I'm creating a list of buttons inside the `scrollView` like a list

- Button 1
- Button 2
- ...

So that they will exceed the size of the view. While creating via code the buttons I'm storing them inside a `NSMutableArray` and then use this code to manage the content size of the `scrollView`

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.arrayOfCreatedButtons!.lastObject!.frame.origin.y + self.arrayOfCreatedButtons!.lastObject!.frame.height)
```

The problem is that the scrollView **DOES NOT** scroll till the last button created but it stops before.

What's the error in my code? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is the code I'm using to create the buttons

```
            let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn.frame = frame! 
            // frame! is a CGRect with variable to create the list of buttons --> y CGFloat is decreased every cycle

            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * btn.bounds.size.width
            btn.layer.masksToBounds = true

            if (self.arrayOfCreatedButtons == nil) {
                self.arrayOfCreatedButtons = NSMutableArray()
            }
            self.arrayOfCreatedButtons?.addObject(btn)

            // Add btn to scrollView
            self.scrollView.addSubview(btn)
```

I'm using it in `viewDidAppear` inside a `for` cycle to create multiple buttons.

And I'm setting the content size **AFTER** all the buttons are created.

Comment: Code looks fine, but how are you creating the buttons? If they are in Storyboard, try moving this code you pasted into `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: I'm creating the buttons programmatically, I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: put a breakpoint there and try `po [self.view recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: @Sulthan Where do you mean to try this piece of code? after `content size` or at the button's creation?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd It's not a piece of code, it's a debugger command which will print the contents of your controller, including all frames and content sizes. Probably this won't be an error in Swift or UIKit but in your code. The easiest way to find your bug is to put a breakpoint somewhere, step through the code and observe the values for frames and the content size. Maybe the content-size is correct and only your scroll view overlaps your controller. Debugging is the fastest way.

Comment: @Sulthan tried but gives me this error `(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
error: <EXPR>:1:12: error: expected ',' separator
[self.view recursiveDescription]
           
^
` Could it be because it's written in Obj-C?

Comment: According to your code, you are decreasing the index of the button. So `lastObject` from array would return the top-most button, not the below button. Try `firstObject` method instead of `lastObject`.

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Oh sure, `po self.view.recursiveDescription()`

Comment: @Legoless no I'm appending each new button so the `lastObject` should be the last created, no?
@Sulthan the command you provided seems not working, so i tried `po self.scrollView.contentSize` and I get 942.2..that's the current value of the last object in the array which is `y: 800` with size `142.2`..I can't spot the issue..

Comment: So if the content size is correct, then you haver another issue, maybe scroll view does not respond to scrolling touches. Can you confirm it has interaction enabled?

Comment: @Legoless yep I can scroll for a certain size but then suddenly stops. For example if I create 9 buttons i can scroll till the 7th, I can see the other 2 left under the current view but i cannot access them in the "visible" screen